# Is there a way to put "continue" inside a foreach arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, break, continue

break and continue statements do not work in Array.forEach(..). 
Is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: You simply do nothing in your lambda instead of explicitly calling ``continue``.

Comment: It depends on the specific use-case. You can use `filter` to filter out elements for which you'd like to "continue" the loop, and there are many things you can do instead of break depending on the use case (`limit()`, `findFirst()`, etc...)

Comment: In short, functional programming doesn't work well with procedural entities like break and continue. `forEach` is not a control structure, it's a method.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in Java 8. You could use an `Exception` to break from code. It's not pretty, but it's doable if you need to.

Like this:

```
try {
    Array.forEach((x) -> {
       if (condition) {
          throw new MyException();
       }
    });
} catch (MyException e) {
    // broke from loop
}
```

Comment: But that will break the execution of the whole loop.

Comment: thats the normal behavior of break